# How jamboards are stored in database

Tags: database, file-format

I'm curious about how Google stores Jamboards in its database. I assume they might be using a NoSQL database, but I'd like to understand the specific storage mechanisms they employ. Could someone please provide insights into how Google handles the storage of Jamboards in their database?